# Protractor: browserName 'chrome' is not supported with directConnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I try to run some tests using protractor on Windows 7 x64, but get the following error:

> ```
> [16:59:18] E/direct - Error code: 135
> [16:59:18] E/direct - Error message: browserName 'chrome' is not supported with directConnect.
> [16:59:18] E/direct - Error: browserName 'chrome' is not supported with directConnect.
>     at IError (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:6:1)
>     at ProtractorError (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:11:9)
>     at BrowserError (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:52:9)
>     at Direct.setupDriverEnv (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:36:23)
>     at Direct.setupEnv (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:111:34)
>     at q.then (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:335:41)
>     at _fulfilled (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
>     at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
>     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
>     at C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\q\q.js:857:14
>     at runSingle (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
>     at flush (C:\Work\GIT\pv-ui\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
>     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>     at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
>     at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>     at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
>
> [16:59:18] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
> ```
>
> node version: v6.11.5
>
> protractor version: 5.2.0

Here is a part of **protractor.conf.js**:

```
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    // seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    directConnect: true,
    allScriptsTimeout:60000,

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            // disable "chrome is being controlled by automated software"
            'args': ['disable-infobars=true'],
            // 'args': ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1400,3000', 'disable-infobars=true'],
            
            // disable Password manager popup
            'prefs': {`enter code here`
                'credentials_enable_service': false
            }
        }
    },

    ...
}
```

Everything works quite fine on MacOS, but fails on Windows 7. Could you please help me to figure out where the problem is?

Comment: hmm, your node is a bit old compared to protractor... unlikely to be the issue and a weird thing to suggest but worked in the past: you can try with a different (newer) node or a different (older) protractor (note: there's this neat thing called `nvm` that allows you to quickly switch between node versions)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to install
`npm install protractor`

Update web driver manager
`webdriver-manager update`

Run this command from your root
`node node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager update`

Now start up a server with:
`webdriver-manager start`

Also make sure that your protractor.conf.js file has below line
`// baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',`
 `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/',`

Now run your e2e tests on different browesers
`ng e2e`